# count the no. of times a cell value changes in googlesheets appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to count the no. of a times a cell value (B2) changes in the sheet....(D2 cell gives the count) I am able to find below code that works for only one cell, but not a range like (B2:B51) ..... any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function onEdit(e)  { incrementCounter_(e); } 
function    incrementCounter_(e) { 
    var sheetToWatch = 'Sheet2'; 
    var cellToWatch =    'B2'; 
    var cellToIncrement = 'D2'; 
    if (!e || !e.range) { return; } 
    var    sheet = e.range.getSheet(); 
    if (sheet.getName() === sheetToWatch &&    e.range.getA1Notation() === cellToWatch)  { 
        var cell =    sheet.getRange(cellToIncrement); 
        cell.setValue((Number(cell.getValue()) || 0) + 1); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the cell edited is within the specific range. This should do the trick.

```
function incrementCounter_(e) { 
  var sheetToWatch = 'Sheet1'; 

  // Define range here 
  // Sample range is B2:B51
  var cellToWatchRange = { 
    top : 2,
    bottom : 51,
    left : 2,
    right : 2
  };

  // Exit if we're out of range or not the sheet we are looking for
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet(); 
  if (thisRow < cellToWatchRange.top || thisRow > cellToWatchRange.bottom
  || thisCol < cellToWatchRange.left || thisCol > cellToWatchRange.right
  || !e || !e.range || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch) {
    return;
  }

  // Offset column to 2 to the right (D)
  var cell = sheet.getRange(thisRow, thisCol + 2); 
  cell.setValue((Number(cell.getValue()) || 0) + 1); 
}
```

Full script in editor:
[image: full script]

Full sheet output:
[image: full sheet]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226108/discussion-between-nazi-a-and-vamsi-gaddam).